# error con laravel 5.3 creando un Shopping Cart

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día
estoy siguiendo un tutorial para Laravel 5.3 y estoy en la implementacion de un carrito de compras pero tengo un error en todo el proyecto por haber llamado a una variable en la siguiente archivo:

resourses/layouts/app.blade

donde coloco:

```
    Mi carrito
    <span class="circle-shopping-cart">
        {{$shopping_cart->productsSize()}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Tengo creado el model de ShoppingCart:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["status"];

    public function productsSize(){
        return 20;
    }

    public static function findOrCreateBySessionID($shopping_cart_id){
        if($shopping_cart_id)
            return ShoppingCart::findBySession($shopping_cart_id);
        else

            return ShoppingCart::createWithoutSession();
    }

    public static function findBySession($shopping_cart_id){
        return ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
    }

    public static function createWithoutSession(){

        return ShoppingCart::created([
            "status" => "incompleted"
        ]);
    }
}
```

y este es su controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\ShoppingCart;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::findOrCreateBySessionID(null);
        return view('main.home',["shopping_cart" => $shopping_cart]);
    }
}
```

Pero me da un error que me dice que el error esta aqui:

```
<li>
    Mi carrito
    <span class="circle-shopping-cart">
        {{$shopping_cart->productsSize()}}
    </span>
</li>
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu último método creas un registro pero te devuelve null, tienes un error de typo

```
// Sustituye created por create
public static function createWithoutSession(){
        return ShoppingCart::create([
            "status" => "incompleted"
        ]);
    }
```

Te recomiendo tambien uses mutadores de manera que sustituyas tu primer método de esta forma

```
public function getProductsSizeAttribute ()
{
        return 20;
}

// De esta forma llamas en el registro asi
$shopping_cart->productsSize; // Sin paréntesis
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu controlador puedes entregar la variable como parámetro de la siguiente manera:

```
return view('main.home',["shopping_cart" => $shopping_cart, "productsCount" => $shopping_cart->productsSize()]);
```

Y luego llamarla directamente en la vista.